# React-native WebView: Load html and js from assets folder

Tags: javascript, webview, react-native, xmlhttprequest, android-assets

I need to load html and js files from assets folder in the WebView. I have tried using :

`<WebView source={{uri: "file:///android_asset/index.html"}} />`

along with `javaScriptEnabled={true}`. The html file is loaded but XMLHttpRequest stops working. I guess it's due to the 'file' protocol.

Is there any other way to access the files in assets folder without using `file:///`? Or in that matter, any other solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way.
Used [react-native-static-server](https://github.com/futurepress/react-native-static-server) to create a server and load html file.